# Fetch random img urls then append to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asynchronous, fetch

Below I am having trouble appending images to an array after fetching them. I have an array defined as `totalMemes` and as it iterates through all the urls, I would like to append to the `totalMemes` array. However, I would then like to pick a random url within the `totalMemes` array and log a single random image from it to the console.

My code below either returns the array as blank, undefined or throws an error that .push is not a function. Essentially having trouble accessing the array especially after fetching all the urls within the json file.
Everything still works if I wanted to `console.log` each link, but I want to end up with it logging one random link out of all.

```js
totalMemes = []
fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => res.data.children)
.then(res => res.map(post => ({
    author: post.data.author,
    link: post.data.url,
    img: post.data.preview.images[0].source.url,
})))

.then(res => res.map(render))
.then(res => console.log(res))

const render = post => {
    totalMemes.push(post.img)
}

setTimeout(() => {
    singleMeme = totalMemes[Math.floor(Math.random() * totalMemes.length)];
    console.log(singleMeme)
}, 900)
```

How is it possible to iterate through all image urls within the json file, and append each iteration to the total array. Then find a random image url out of the array and output to console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are assuming that the remote fetching operation will always be completed in 900ms. Then you try to process the data after this interval. It might well be that the response hasn't arrived when you try to process data.

Instead of guessing the response arrival time and delaying the data processing, you need to do your data processing after the data is received. In other words you should do it in another `.then` method.

```
.then(() => {

    singleMeme = totalMemes[Math.floor(Math.random() * totalMemes.length)];
    console.log(singleMeme)

})
```

Here is a running code:

```js
totalMemes = []
fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => res.data.children)
.then(res => res.map(post => ({
    author: post.data.author,
    link: post.data.url,
    img: post.data.preview.images[0].source.url,
})))

.then(res => res.map(render))
.then(() => {

    singleMeme = totalMemes[Math.floor(Math.random() * totalMemes.length)];
    console.log(singleMeme)

})

const render = post => {
    totalMemes.push(post.img)
}
```